# Где выполнять примеры кода к книге Thinking in Java Брюса Эккеля, если большинство IDE выдают ошибки?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse

Скачал папку с кодом на *Github*, вставил в **src** в *IntellijIDEA*, выдалось несколько сотен ошибок компиляции. Не обратил на это внимание, удалил всё из **src** и просто качал по одному классу.

Потом на середине книги пришлось загрузить его пакет **typeinfo**, которая в *IntellijIDEA* не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-либо способы запустить этот код. Подача материала очень нравится и не хочется менять способ обучения.

Ссылка на код: https://github.com/BruceEckel/TIJ4-code/tree/master/examples

Comment: [This code is designed to work outside of IDEs. Because packages are not introduced until later chapters, and some of the fancier IDEs like Eclipse require all code to be in packages, if you want to use the code inside those IDEs you will have to make some adjustments (however, see the Eclipse.py program in the download package for some help). Different IDEs have different requirements and it may be more trouble than it's worth while you're getting started; instead, you may want to begin with a more basic editor like JEdit](https://github.com/BruceEckel/TIJ4-code)

Comment: как вы подключили библиотеку typeinfo к проекту в intellij idea?

Comment: скопировал package typeinfo с Github и вставил в src проекта

Answer (score 1):

1. Клонировать проект к себе на компьютер
2. Открыть проект через кнопку open

   [image: Пример использования кнопки open в idea]

и выбрать папку с названием проекта

[image: Выбор папку с названием проекта]

3. Установить плагин `Ant Support`. Для этого нужно будет Открыть File->Settings-Plugins-> Ищете `Ant Support`. Нажимаете установить, перезапускате idea

[image: Установка плагина]

4. Справа должна появится вкладочка Ant Build, на неё нужно нажать, там будет `+`
   после чего нужно выбрать файл build.xml и импортировать лучше файл, с той дирректории, с которой будете работать, например `TIJ4-code/examples/access/build.xml`
   **(Осторожно тут указано в файле build версия java 1.5, чтобы запустить я исправлял на 1.7)**
   [image: Импорт файла сборки]
5. После импорта нужно собрать его выбрав **build** и нажав зеленую стрелочку[image: Сборка ant]
6. После корректной сборки, у вас справа появится список классов, который вы сможете выполнять [image: Запуск класса через плагин]